# ComplexWarning when calling convolve2d() in SciPy, why?

Tags: python, scipy, convolution

When I run

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
convolve2d([[2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0]], [[0.5], [0.5]], 'valid')
```

I get

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 422
    return sigtools._convolve2d(in1, in2, 1, val, bval, fillvalue)
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

Why am I getting this, and how do I properly prevent it?

Comment: What version of scipy are you using?  I get the warning with scipy 0.11.0, but not when I run scipy built from the latest source code, so apparently this has been fixed.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Ah, I'm using 0.11.0 as well... I'll try 0.12 then, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I just tried 0.12.0 (which is the latest release), and I don't get the warning.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Awesome, feel free to post it as an answer! :)

Comment: For the some reason error is still presented in `scipy.signal.sigtools._convolve2d` in case of direct call (without `scipy.signal.convolve2d`)... Does anybody know a reason? I use scipy 0.15.0

Comment: UPD: found that error still occurs only if I use `flip=1` in `_convolve2d`. With `flip=0` (default) this bug is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in release 0.12.0.